# Prevent popup showing up with Webauthn

Tags: javascript, fido-u2f

When implementing a service that uses the [Webauthn](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn) protocol to allow users to register and sign in with a U2F key it always shows a popup. I find the user experience of that not so great, since the popup covers up the area where I try to guide the user.

I find this user experience much nicer: https://mdp.github.io/u2fdemo

The answer is probably "No", but maybe I've missed it: Is it possible to control the user experience with Webauthn? Specifically, it is possible to prevent the popup from showing up?

Comment: Hi, elaborate more, put your code which you using triggers popup. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting please

Comment: It's the difference in experience between https://webauthn.io/ and https://mdp.github.io/u2fdemo. I'd like to make use the Webauthn standards, but have the experience of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: U2F does not show a popup, WebAuthn does

WebAuthn doesn't allow preventing the popup, see https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1251. Hopefully it will be improved in the future so that it is less distracting.
The old U2F API does not trigger a popup. As described in the link above, there's a reason for that popup. I don't recommend to use the old U2F API for new implementations as it won't be supported forever.